# What does "he's had it" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Arthur, you know Mad-Eye," said Mr. Diggory's head, rolling its eyes again. "Someone creeping into his yard in the dead of night? More likely there's a very shell-shocked cat wandering around somewhere, covered in potato peelings. But if the Improper Use of Magic lot get their hands on Mad-Eye, **he's had it** -- think of his record -- we've got to get him off on a minor charge, something in your department -- what are exploding dustbins worth?"

The phrase "have it" has a lot of meanings according to dictionaries, such as:

> 1. To take or use something.
> 2. To know something.
> 3. To understand, comprehend, or grasp something.
> 4. To claim or maintain that something is the case.
> 5. To win a vote.

It might have other meanings too. But I can't figure out what it means exactly in this context. How should we understand it in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it likely means "he's done for." (A native British-English speaker may be able to confirm this.)

Comment: As a native British-English speaker, this use means something like: this time he will not only receive a warning for the trouble he causes; this time the authorities will punish him severely.

Comment: While you are (more or less) correct, it would be a good idea to explain the idiom "done for" in plain English.

Comment: @Andrew Oh, you're right, I guess explaining an idiom with another idiom isn't especially helpful

Comment: More-or-less the second definition [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+had+it).